# Add string (API) as a single variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to combine the results of the select / option in a variable (it belongs to the URL of an API) and I am new handling Typescrip, then I get several errors and other things that I don't know how to do.
For example, add the results of select / option (url next to cat, diff, type) and then save it in a localStorage to call it to another component (as it did in javascript)

**html**

```
<h5>Select Type:</h5>
            <form name="formul2" class="cont">
              <div class="box">
                <select id="type" name="type" [(ngModel)]="typ">
                  <option value="">Any Type</option>
                  <option value="&type=multiple">Multple Choice</option>
                  <option value="&type=boolean">True / False</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </form>
            <a class="btn" id="fetch" href="game">Play</a>
            <a class="btn" href="highscores">High Scores</a>
```

**TS**

```
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public diff:string;

  public cat:string;

  public typ:string;
}

const url:string = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20';

var newUrl:string = url + diff + cat + typ;

var x = document.getElementById('fetch')

x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem("urlGame", newUrl);
});
```

Comment: 1. `url`, `newUrl` , `x` can't just dangle around somewhere - you need to place them within your class.  2. `x.addEventListener(...)` needs to be wrapped in a method. 3. Read up about forms in angular, thereby on submit of the form you can *retrieve* the desired values of the form elements and process them according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a change listener method on the select element

```
<select id="type" name="type" [(ngModel)]="typ" (chnage)="setChange(typ)">
  <option value="">Any Type</option>
  <option value="&type=multiple">Multple Choice</option>
  <option value="&type=boolean">True / False</option>
</select>
```

Component

```
const url: string = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20';
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public diff: string;

  public cat: string;

  public typ: string;

  public newUrl: string;

  public setChange(selectedValue: any) {
    this.newUrl = url + this.diff + this.cat + selectedValue;
    localStorage.setItem('urlGame', this.newUrl);
  }
}
```

You can use "ngx-webstorage-service" for local storage

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtlm4f)

Comment: I have three select elements, do I put the setChange () method on all three? (setChange (typ), setChange (diff), setChange (cat))

Comment: Basically if you bind seperate ngModel with every element, those variables will automatically gets the updated value. Not necessarily required to listen for all the change event

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about the data type then you can simple initialize as **any**

```
  public any_variable: any;
```

Try this :

```
let url:string = "https://www.example.com";
let any_variable:string = `${url}/api/${diff}`;
```

Comment: but those variable are string

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to achieve is this as you final url:

```
https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20/diff/cat/typ
```

If this is the case then it can be achieved using string template as follows:

```
var newUrl:string = `${this.url}/${this.diff}/${this.cat}/${this.typ}`
```